# JavaScript Force Event To Fire (Twitter API) (JQuery Context Menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, twitter, contextmenu

I'm using the Twitter API to embed tweets on a page.  I'm trying to bind a JQuery context menu to the `<a>` tags in each tweet by attaching it to the selectors ".hashtag" and ".profile".  These CSS classes are already applied to the anchor tags by twitter.  The context menu is configured to show up on right clicks.

The problem is the context menu doesn't show up though, I'm assuming somehow the right click event is being blocked by some of Twitter's code so the event isn't getting to the JQuery Context Menu?  I've successfully been able to create my own `<a>` tags and have the context menu work with those so my code is correct.

Not much code to show since libraries are doing most of the work but here is how I'm initializing the context menu, done in $.ready:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.hashtag, .profile',
    build: function ($triggerElement, e) {
        console.log(e);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Show us some code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you return false on the build command the contextmenu will not be shown. So if this really is the way you initialize, it won't work.

Have a look at: http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#build

There is also i typo in your keycode, it should be keyCode, with capital.